# compiling problems

Tags: compiling

I have got below error message when I tried running a program.

```
undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
f11.c:(.text+0x24d): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
f11.c:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
f11.c:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
f11.c:(.text+0x286): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
```

and so on.

what is the problem exactly? It is running fine with 11.04 version, please help!

---

i reinstalled the gcc, but problem still exist
i used a command like this:  g++ -lfftw3  -lcpgplot -lpgplot f11.c.
the out puts are: 
undefined reference tofftw_malloc' f11.c:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to fftw_malloc' f11.c:(.text+0x273): undefined reference tofftw_malloc' f11.c:(.text+0x286): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc

undefined reference to `cpgbeg'
f11.c:(.text+0x2d3c): undefined reference to`cpgpage'
f11.c:(.text+0x2d49): undefined reference to `cpgsch'
f11.c:(.text+0x2d71): undefined reference to`cpgsvp'
please give me suggestion.

Comment: What are you trying to compile, How are you trying to compile, did you followed the always included instructions?, do you *have* instructions?, need more info.

Comment: the basic compiling commands are `./configure` then `make` and then `sudo make install` that last command requiers you to typ in your password!

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so Ubuntu package `libfftw3-dev` is installed, which is obvious as you would get an error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3
```

instead if the library was not found by the linker.

There is a hint in the [gcc linker documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Link-Options.html) saying that the order of files given to the linker is important. Citing from the documentation

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option [-l *library*]; the
>   linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
>   they are specified. Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after
>   file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in z, those
>   functions may not be loaded.

In your case, no functions referenced by `f11.c` are being loaded from the specified library, since they are listed *before* `f11.c`. This is somewhat counterintuitive, but I am pretty sure that compiling with

```
g++ f11.c -lfftw3 -lcpgplot -lpgplot
```

will be the solution to your problem. You may need to check the order of the libraries though, in case they depend on each other. In general, if (file or library) x depends on (file or library) y, make sure that x is listed before y on the command line given to the linker.

Comment: yes, i installed that package.

Comment: @msPeachy - I have edited my post so that now it can be regarded a valid answer. Your comment is contradictory though: You suggested that I better used a comment on the authors post, but noted that it was impossible for me to do so, given my reputation. Huh?

Comment: @MartinDirichs my comment said once you have *sufficient* reputation. Anyway, since you've modified your answer, I would now delete my previous comment. Thank you.

Comment: @user92371 I am glad my answer was helpful. Please consider making it the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are missing dynamic libraries of some kind. probably standard C libs and fast fourier transform. Try to reinstall your compiler - it might help. and the second thing to do it to create once more your fast fourier lib that you are trying to link.

Comment: thank you, let me try. but actually it is run well in ubuntu 11.04